# How to post images to server using ASIFormDataRequest?

Tags: ios, image-uploading, asiformdatarequest

How to upload a image to server using ASIFormDataRequest ?
i tried to upload a image its does't show's any error while inserting. and in my requesting did finished method iam getting  response as success. so what is the problem is, when i get the data what i have inserted in that i am not able to get the image what i have inserted but iam getting the image path also.

here is my code

```
NSString *globalurl =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"Global_Url"];

NSString *urlStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/InsertUserInfo?User_Name=%@&User_Pwd=%@&User_FName=%@&User_LName=%@&User_Mail=%@&User_Phno=%@&User_Address=%@&User_Dob=%@&Ic_No=%@&User_Active=%@&User_Questions=%@&User_Ans=%@",globalurl,usernameTxtFld.text,pwdTxtFld.text,firstName.text,lastName.text,email.text,phonNO.text,address.text,dateOfbirth.text,nricNo.text,@"10001",@"",@""];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request addData:dataImage withFileName:@"Image.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"photo"];
//check if passedData is nil
if (dataImage == nil)
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title:iDnil" message:@"nil" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"fgff" otherButtonTitles:@"erer", nil];
    [alert show];
}
[request startAsynchronous];

 -(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

NSString *receivedString = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"received messge %@",receivedString);
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:receivedString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView show];
 }


      - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
     {
dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"],1);
NSLog(@"dict is %@",info);
UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use AFNetworking, it is under current development.

Comment: ok i will try using afnetworking

Comment: Where are you uploading the image data? have you re checked your globalurl ?

Comment: I have worked enough of uploading images to the server using ASIHttp-Request, I can definitely help you!please give out the issue informations.

Comment: Check my example application on the link- as given in the answers.

Comment: @thatzprem in my app i have upload a image to server.i can selected image from iphone gallary for i can take image using my iphone camera. so when i tried to upload image while inserting i am not getting any error message but also,i have check the result by using get server and i have checked in server side there the image size is showing '1kb', iam  not understanding whts wrong in it, i am using ASIFormDataRequest

Comment: Why is the size of the image that you are uploading? Are you using server of your own or some test servers?

Comment: can u provide ur example application link

Comment: https://github.com/thatzprem/FileUpload-Example

Comment: yeah i tried it but u r  using the image which is on ur nsbundle

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`[request setFile:@"YOUR IMAGE FILE PATH" forKey:@"photo"];`
instead of `[request addData:dataImage withFileName:@"Image.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"photo"];`
 as explained in the [post](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) . It worked for me like a charm :-)

Comment: but how to get path of the image form iphone gallary

Comment: You can save the image from iphone gallary to your document directory.And then give the path of the image which is present in document didectory

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded an example application performing textfile, Image, Video, Images upload in queue, Videos to GitHub on this [link](https://github.com/thatzprem/FileUpload-Example.git). You may well consider having a look at it.

ASI-http-request has an optimisation option to stream your image files right away from your disk, which is the best I've seen with this library. Please consider using the below code snippet for creating ASIFormDataRequest.

```
    // Initilize Variables
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:IMAGE_POST_URL];

    // Add Image
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"image1" ofType:@"jpg"];

    // Get Image
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]
                         initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    // Return if there is no image
    if(imageData != nil){

        //Request-1
        ASIFormDataRequest * request1;
        [request1 setTag:201];

        request1 = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [request1 setPostValue:@"ID = 201" forKey:@"image_upload"];
        [request1 setFile:path forKey:@"image1_file"];
        [request1 setDelegate:self];
        [request1 setDidFinishSelector:@selector(imageUploadDidFinish:)];
        [request1 setDidFailSelector:@selector(imageUploadDidFail:)];
        [request1 setTimeOutSeconds:500];
        [request1 setShouldStreamPostDataFromDisk:YES];
}
```

Comment: but her image is not in my bundle file i have to select from iphone gallary